# ServletWrapping Controller URL Throwing 404

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I have an AJAX request that is posting to the URL `http://localhost:8080/spellchecker/google-spellchecker.do` which is mapped below.  Any idea why this is throwing a 404 error?  I have a `System.out.println("==========");` in `GoogleSpellChekerServlet.service()` and it doesn't get called.

```
<!-- Setup Spring ServletWrappers -->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/spellchecker/google-spellchecker.do">googleSpellChekerWrappingController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="googleSpellChekerWrappingController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController">
    <property name="servletClass">
        <value>org.tinymce.spellchecker.GoogleSpellChekerServlet</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here's a screenshot of the ajax request...

[image: Screenshot of ajax request]

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Under what context name is your web application deployed? The AJAX request would only work if this application is ROOT.war.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek - The context path is `/`.  I'm testing by hitting "Run" in Netbeans on Windows.

Comment: I would be more easy to understand your problem if you can put the jsp code from where you are calling the ajax request.

Comment: @JapanTrivedi - I've included a screenshot to show the request.  The request is coming from tinyMCE so it's not very easy for me to give you the actual ajax code.

Comment: You need to show us the servlet mapping section of your `web.xml` for anyone to be able to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @mattb - Good thinking... done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web.xml isn't mapping *.do to the servlet.